# Guardar la información de un chat Cliente/servidor en un archivo .txt

Tags: c, servidor, txt

Este es el código que tengo de la parte del servidor, lo que no logro hacer es que la información del chat se guarde en un txt, también como podría hacer que ese txt guarde la fecha y hora en la que se creo. ¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? Me seria de mucha ayuda, espero alguien pueda ayudarme gracias.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"sys/types.h"
#include"netinet/in.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"sys/socket.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"unistd.h"


main(){

int sd,i,len,bi,nsd,port;
char content[100];
struct sockaddr_in ser,cli;

    if((sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))==-1){
        printf("\n Problema al crear el socket");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\n Socket creado exitosamente\n");
    bzero((char*)&cli,sizeof(ser));
    ser.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ser.sin_port=htons(7070);
    ser.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    bi=bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&ser,sizeof(ser));

    if(bi==-1){
        printf("\n Puerto ocupado, por favor, cambia el puerto en el cliente y en el servidor");
        return 0;
    }

    i=sizeof(cli);
    listen(sd,5);
    nsd = accept(sd,((struct sockaddr *)&cli),&i);
    
    if(nsd==-1){
        printf("\nrevisa el parametro\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nConexion aceptada");

    if(fork()){
        printf("\n Comienza a chatear con el cliente o pulse exit para salir:\n");
        scanf("%s",content);
        while(strcmp(content,"exit")!=0){
            send(nsd,content,strlen(content)+1,0);
            scanf("%s",content);
        }
    send(nsd,"exit",5,0);
    }

    else
        i = recv(nsd,content,100,0);
        while(strcmp(content,"exit")!=0){
            printf("\nMensaje del cliente: %s\n",content);
            i=recv(nsd,content,100,0);
        }

        while(strcmp(content,"exit")!=0){
            printf("\n Recibido del cliente %s\n",content);
            i=recv(nsd,content,30,0);
        }

    
    printf("\n Adios");
    send(nsd,"EOF",4,0);
    close(sd);
    close(nsd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!